# Using SVG image for background in a DIV component

Tags: reactjs, svg, styled-components

How can i use SVG for a background image in a div?
I'm using styled components.

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

export const StyledStepBox = styled.div`
  width: 30%;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
`;
```

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="274" height="568" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 274 568"><rect width="274" height="568" fill="#483EFF" rx="10"/><mask id="a" width="274" height="568" x="0" y="0" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" style="mask-type:alpha"><rect width="274" height="568" fill="#fff" rx="10"/></mask><g mask="url(#a)"><path fill="#6259FF" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M-34.692 543.101C3.247 632.538 168.767 685.017 211.96 612.52c43.194-72.497-66.099-85.653-104.735-160.569-38.635-74.916-68.657-121.674-124.482-104.607-55.824 17.068-55.375 106.32-17.436 195.757Z" clip-rule="evenodd"/><path fill="#F9818E" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M233.095 601.153c60.679-28.278 92.839-143.526 41.875-171.528-50.965-28.003-57.397 47.579-108.059 75.987-50.662 28.408-82.14 50.207-69.044 88.241 13.096 38.034 74.549 35.578 135.228 7.3Z" clip-rule="evenodd"/><path stroke="#fff" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="bevel" stroke-width="5" d="m165.305 469.097 10.607-10.806M209.461 474.581l-12.506-10.503M187.56 488.991l-6.908 14.798"/><path fill="#FFAF7E" d="M.305 546.891c37.003 0 67-29.997 67-67s-29.997-67-67-67-67 29.997-67 67 29.997 67 67 67Z"/></g></svg>
```

Expecting that the div has the background with this svg.

Answer (score 0):

You can add it like any other [`background-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image).

Alternatively, you can encode the SVG and add it directly to your CSS.  For the best results, I recommend using single quotes for properties and uri encode `<,>,#,/`.  There are lots of online converters (or write your own).  I like this [url-coverter](https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder/).

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

export const StyledStepBox = styled.div`
  width: 30%;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='274' height='568' fill='none' viewBox='0 0 274 568'%3E%3Crect width='274' height='568' fill='%23483EFF' rx='10'/%3E%3Cmask id='a' width='274' height='568' x='0' y='0' maskUnits='userSpaceOnUse' style='mask-type:alpha'%3E%3Crect width='274' height='568' fill='%23fff' rx='10'/%3E%3C/mask%3E%3Cg mask='url(%23a)'%3E%3Cpath fill='%236259FF' fill-rule='evenodd' d='M-34.692 543.101C3.247 632.538 168.767 685.017 211.96 612.52c43.194-72.497-66.099-85.653-104.735-160.569-38.635-74.916-68.657-121.674-124.482-104.607-55.824 17.068-55.375 106.32-17.436 195.757Z' clip-rule='evenodd'/%3E%3Cpath fill='%23F9818E' fill-rule='evenodd' d='M233.095 601.153c60.679-28.278 92.839-143.526 41.875-171.528-50.965-28.003-57.397 47.579-108.059 75.987-50.662 28.408-82.14 50.207-69.044 88.241 13.096 38.034 74.549 35.578 135.228 7.3Z' clip-rule='evenodd'/%3E%3Cpath stroke='%23fff' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='bevel' stroke-width='5' d='m165.305 469.097 10.607-10.806M209.461 474.581l-12.506-10.503M187.56 488.991l-6.908 14.798'/%3E%3Cpath fill='%23FFAF7E' d='M.305 546.891c37.003 0 67-29.997 67-67s-29.997-67-67-67-67 29.997-67 67 29.997 67 67 67Z'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  background-size: cover;
`;
```